# How important is my Master's degree after obtaining a PhD?

Tags: phd, masters, europe

I am about to complete my Master's and start a PhD. While I probably should not concern myself too much about what comes after a PhD when I have not even started it, there is something that has been weighing on my mind.

**TL;DR:** Assuming I finish my PhD, is it worthwhile to improve my M.Sc. grade from "good" to "very good"?

I expect to get a pretty good grade on my master's thesis, but overall I will finish with a GPA of 1.6 ([German grading scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_grading_in_Germany)). If I took on an extra project last minute, I could improve it to 1.5 (my gut feeling tells me this is a bad idea with everything else I have going on). This seems like a small difference, but on paper, at least in my country, this is the threshold of being able to write "*M.Sc. 1.5 (very good)*" instead of "*M.Sc. 1.6 (good)*".

I have to decide soon if I want to do an extra course project or keep focusing on research before I hand in my thesis. My Master's and my PhD are in the same area on pretty much the same research topic. This is in Europe and I will be staying in the same research group for my PhD as I wrote my Master's thesis with (same supervisor).

Comment: What is your goal post-PhD? Do you plan to work in academia, or move to industry? In my experience, in the non-academic work world, what matters is what you did last. Once you have a few years of work experience, your school grades don't matter much at all. The fact that you have advanced degrees will be a plus, but even that becomes less important as you gain work experience. (How important depends on your field. In some fields your credentials will always matter, and in others, after 10 years on the job they become almost irrelevant.)

Comment: Overemphasis on grades can get in the way of learning. I encourage my grad students to take at least one course where they are at risk of getting a C (US system). Something outside their core expertise, something outside their comfort zone. School isn’t just for accreditation, it’s for learning too. :)

Comment: I have no particular insights into how hiring managers make decisions in the real world, but I do find it easy to imagine that for many - perhaps most - jobs, the assessed learning outcomes of a master's degree are more relevant than the single assessed learning outcome of a PhD, so a hypothetical rational hiring manager would put consderable weight on the master's grade.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For the most part, your MSc transcripts become completely irrelevant post-PhD. Only rarely will (academic*) job applications even ask for transcripts. When they do this usually due to some formal policy requiring this and they carry very little weight in the decision making process.

If you passed you MSc with particular honors (e.g. "cum laude"), some people will note this on their CV. But, this too provides only a very minor plus to their profile. For post-PhD academic positions the main thing that will count is the impact you have had on your field (through publications, conference presentations). For junior postdoc positions (and fellowships) the quality of your PhD advisor and institution may carry some weight (I know it did for my first postdoc).

*I can't speak for positions outside of academia, but I'm sure someone else will comment on this.

Comment: Thank you for your perspective, that really puts my mind at ease! I think my concern also stemmed from comparing myself to others, I am trying to do that less :-)

Answer (score 24):

One case where the MSc may not be entirely irrelevant after a PhD is if the field of studies are not the same. For example, if you did a master's in physics and went on to do a PhD in machine learning.

This can be a small plus by showing that you may bring a bit of a broader perspective to things, in addition to demonstrating that you are able to quickly get deep knowledge even in a somewhat new field.

Comment: This can actually be a big plus if an employer is looking for somebody who has deep knowledge of e.g. machine learning, but who "speaks the same language" as e.g. physicists who make up a significant proportion of his technical staff.

Answer (score 10):

My perspective: I hold a PhD from an American institution and I have transitioned to a non-academic career in the US. So I will speak to the utility of advanced credentials and grades in this context. I will also answer the question in the post rather than the title.

**Grades become dramatically less important after your first job.**

What matters in finding a job are proofs of the skills you can bring to the workplace. In order of decreasing importance, three important types of proofs are:

1. What you have accomplished
2. Who can endorse that you have these skills
3. Credentials (i.e., credible institutions that endorse your skills)

(I do not claim these are the only types of proof)

Of course these are all connected. For example in the course of earning a credential, or in the course of accomplishing work, you begin to build a network of people who know you and your skills. Or in the course of accomplishing work, you may earn a professional credential. And so on.

There are some exceptions to the **bolded rule** above. One is if you are making a career transition. In that case, you do not have access to options (1) and (2) above; you have to fall back on your credentials, and grades help deepen the picture of your skills.

For example, if I am hiring a software engineer, and I see one applicant is an accountant with no prior software experience who has earned an MS in Computer Science online, I would like to also see grades and school projects as evidence of their skills.

I'm speaking in the context of non-academic careers, but I believe this is also true in academic careers. Once you've proven yourself with research and teaching, and built professional friendships in your sub-field, you are a known quantity: You don't need to tout your grades or even your degrees as you search for a next job.

**Overall, degrees, grades, and other credentials are evidence you can use to help answer this question: "How will this person accomplish the tasks required of this role and add value to the company?"** Hopefully this is a useful frame of reference to evaluate decisions in the context of what happens after you finish the next degree.

*Again please note I'm speaking from my experience in the US - I do not know Germany's system well enough to comment on particulars, although I would *believe* that the general principles still hold*

Answer (score 7):

I just completed my MSc at university of Edinburgh in 2022. Our lecturers told us just get it done, as employers in the UK don't ask for grades. The only time the grade is important is when applying for PhDs, then you need a distinction grade (UK scoring) otherwise a borderline credit with a very good academic reference.

Answer (score 3):

If you leave academia after your PhD, you are often hired for your Master's degree. In most cases, when you job hunt, the PhD is formally not finished because the final steps like review, defense, publication, or certificate are missing.

Industry in general has a hard time to evaluate how well you did as a PhD student: Good institute, great advisor, decent citations, well-received talked, best paper awards, important contributions to the field cannot be judged. Industry keeps asking for high school diploma, bachelor's and master's grades, even if you achieved a stellar PhD. Same is true for the public sector unless it is focused on research.

Comment: Disagree here (Western Europe). Usually industry asks for the confirmation that you finished, not the grades. (Also people know that grades do not say much..)

Comment: @user111388 You are right, but the confirmation can only be give after the defense. When funding ends, you have to look for a job or live from your savings.

Comment: @usr134567: The questioner asks us if it is worth to increase the master grade. I'm saying it's not, people will only check if they finished the Master's (whereas you say industry looks for master grades). Or do I understand you wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**If you plan to go into tech (and tech-related) industry, your MSc is at least as important as your PhD.**

MSc is seen as "practical" knowledge and this is the title that is required and understood. In Europe you would often get an "engineer" title alongside.

A PhD is a nice to have, it can even be a (slight) problem as you may be seen as overqualified for the entry job you will be getting.

That's for the diplomas.

**The grade you got has zero value**, it does not matter and it would be weird to list it. An exception would be the local equivalent of *summa cum laude* which is a nice touch. Your articles as part of the PhD do not matter either. The titles of your thesis are mildly informative at best.

Generally speaking, the industry you get into looks at your MSc to see that you have a basic set of knowledge and you will grow from there.

Notes:

- Of course, this is for generic positions. If you go into industry-research then it is another story and the PhD is fundamental.
- Some countries (notably Germany) put a very strong weight on the PhD which becomes a social title

Answer (score 1):

> I am about to complete my Master's and start a PhD.

There are many examples on this site of people who could not finish their Ph.D. for reasons that don't depend on them. As of now, I think you should focus on your Master before thinking about the post-Ph.D.

**You should consider how much effort that extra project would cost.** The cost/ratio may be in favor of doing it.

1. Other people said grades don't matter for getting a job in the private sector but, let's be honest, all other things being equal, a recruiter would probably favor a *very good* M.Sc over a *good* one.
2. This extra project (and your dedication and efforts you are willing to make) could be the story that "sells you" to a recruiter during an interview.
3. In some countries (e.g. South Korea), grades actually matter when applying for a job. You never know where life will lead you, better to have the best cards to deal with future events!
4. There is a small chance you need to interrupt your Ph.D. and find a new supervisor. This extra project mentioned in a recommendation letter could help you enter a new Ph.D. program.
5. At worst, a boost in confidence before starting a Ph.D. is not negligible.

Of course, as others mentioned, if all goes well and you end up in academia after finishing your Ph.D., your grades in Master's would not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if your masters thesis and doctoral thesis were in different areas withing the profession, that may be an interesting tidbit.

Generally, PhD means you know how to do ad-tech/research in one area of the field; it doesn't necessarily mean more practical skill/knowledge in other areas. As such it tends to be an important degree for academia, or for companies looking for specialized knowledge, or for positions which are more academic than applied and involved research rather than design. If the company has a research division (fewer can afford one, these days) it or a superb masters' thesis can help you get in the door there.

But for most jobs a degree is certification as a practitioner of the field in lieu of (more) years of experience, rather than as researcher or instructor.

Depending on what the PhD was about and why the candidate says they pursued it and what they can say about how that focus benefits me as an employer, it may or may not be a plus. Depending on what kind of position I'm hiring for and how unhappy I think this individual will be with less than cutting-edge work and whether their work can translate directly into what I need, it *might* be a minus, but for me that would be on an individual basis, not merely that someone was having fun and decided they wanted to explore that track.

If you jumped to doctoral candidate without finishing your masters, I would *probably* consider acceptance into the former as evidence that the school thought you were already operating at a masters level.